# Calling other CGI perl files within a file

Tags: perl, cgi

Is there a way to call/access other cgi files within the same file. For example: in PHP, a require or include can call other php files. Something similar to that. I'm trying to avoid writing out a large file and trying to separate the codes in different files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the standard method for importing modules in Perl?

Like this:

```
use mymodule;
```

at the beginning of your perl file.  Then you will have another perl file named `mymodule.pm` in the same directory as your main program, and that perl file must begin with:

```
package mymodule;
```

in order to declare it as the `mymodule` module, and it must end with:

```
1;
```

in order to return success when your main program finished reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really want to call other CGI programs. I bet what you really want to do is to package up some common functionality into modules which you can then use in all of your CGI programs.